# Android - Why would SaxParser work on local XML file, but not on an XML at a URL?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, saxparser

I have successfully implemented SaxParser in my application to parse XML files. My app works well with other online XML files, but not with a specific one. I opened this specific XML file on my browser than went to "page source", copied everything and pasted inside a local XML file in my project, and the parser worked.

When I try to parse this file from it's source on internet, on Logcat I get error message:

```
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: syntax error
```

The only thing comes to my mind is, the source file's url is something like "example.com/showxml". So the url does not end with a .xml extension.

Can this be the cause of the error?

Thanks in advance!

Notes:
1. Internet permission is listed in my manifest.
2. I don't think there is a syntax error in the XML file, since it worked when I copy & paste it to a local file.

UPDATE:

I uploaded the XML file to another website, in order to try if I can reach it from there. And it worked. Seems like my problem is caused by the domain that I am trying to get the original file from.

Answer (score 1):

dump the file inside android, perhaps your code is using the wrong char encoding, bad bof etc.

Comment: The problem was caused because of my misunderstanding. Thank you anyway for sharing your idea.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there was a huge mistake by me. The file was not an XML file, it was JSON. But somehow, Firefox was showing it in XML format, and giving me huge confusion. I guess the URL I was calling was some kind of a webservice which is able to return the data both in XML and JSON formats. Anyway, problem solved. Thanks to everyone who spend a minute here.